# SVG pointer-events and stroke-dasharray

Tags: css, svg, pointer-events, stroke-dasharray

In the next example I'm drawing an ellipse with no fill and a stroke-dasharray. The `pointer-events` is set to `visibleStroke` or `stroke`. When I mouse over the stroke the circle inside should change it's `fill` and the `stroke`:

```css
ellipse:hover ~ circle {
  fill: LightSkyBlue;
  stroke: DodgerBlue;
}
```

The definition from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events):

> **visibleStroke:**
>   SVG only. The element can only be the target of a mouse event when the visibility property is set to visible and when the mouse cursor is over the perimeter (i.e., stroke) of the element. **The value of the stroke property does not affect event processing**.

In the next example when I'm mousing over the dashes everything is as expected. However when I'm mousing over the gaps nothing happens. Even more: in Chrome the insensitive gaps seams to be offsetted. Is this a bug or a feature?

```css
figure {
  width: 200px;
  height: 230px;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  margin:1em;
}
figure::before {
  content: attr(data-pe);
  visibility: visible;
  color: indigo;
  background: skyBlue;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
ellipse {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #d9d9d9;
  stroke-dasharray: 4 3;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
ellipse:hover ~ circle {
  fill: LightSkyBlue;
  stroke: DodgerBlue;
}
circle {
  fill: royalBlue;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 2;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<figure data-pe="visibleStroke">
    <svg viewBox="-12 -12 24 24">
      <ellipse rx="9" ry="9" style="pointer-events:visibleStroke;"></ellipse>
      <circle r="5"></circle>
    </svg>
</figure>
```

Comment: The value of the stroke property does not affect processing, it says nothing about the value of the stroke-dasharray property. Firefox works like Chrome so if there's already browser compatibility, that's the way it is. There appears to be no offsetting in Firefox so perhaps that part is a Chrome bug.

Comment: I'm not sure this a bug. You can solve this problem by adding a transparent ellipse under the dashed one.